# create a trigger to derive column values from another table

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle11g

I have two tables

```
Items

ITEM_CODE   VARCHAR2(20)    
ITEM_NAME   VARCHAR2(20)
PRICE_TON   NUMBER(38,5)    
PRICE_REAM  NUMBER(38,5)    
PRICE_SHEET NUMBER(38,5)

Orderitems

ORDER_ITEMS_CODE    VARCHAR2(20)    
ORDER_CODE          VARCHAR2(20)    
ITEM_CODE_ORDERS    VARCHAR2(20)
ORDER_QUANTITY          NUMBER(4,0) 
ORDER_UNIT          VARCHAR2(5)
UNIT_PRICE          NUMBER(38,5)
```

I want to create a trigger to calculate unit_price based on order_unit 
I tried this trigger but it didn't work

```
 create or replace TRIGGER "Orderitems_T1"
    BEFORE
    insert or update on orderitems
    for each row
    begin   
    declare
    order_unit                        orderitems.order_unit%type;
    unit_price                         orderitems.unit_price%type;
    price_sheet                      Items.price_sheet%type;
    price_ream                       Items.price_ream%type;
    price_ton                           Items.price_ton%type;
    item_code                         Items.item_code%type;
    item_code_orders         orderitems.item_code_orders%type;
    when item_code_orders = item_code then
    begin
    case
    when order_unit ='sheet' then  unit_price :=  price_sheet;
    when order_unit = 'ton'  then  unit_price := price_ton ;
    when order_unit = 'ream'  then  unit_price := price_ream ;
    else unit_price  := 0;
    end case;
    end;
    end;
```

I recieve this error

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure subtype type   current cursor delete exists prior

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: case The symbol "case" was substituted for ";" to continue.

Comment: The WHEN clause you've specified is in the wrong place, but more to the point you're naming one field (ITEM_CODE_ORDERS) which exists in the ORDERITEMS table, and another field (ITEM_CODE) which exists in the ITEMS table.  All the fields named in the WHEN clause must exist in the table on which the trigger operates (in this case the ORDERITEMS table).  Please edit your question and explain more about what you're trying to accomplish.  Thanks.

Comment: I want to calculate the unit_price for each item inserted in table ORDERITEMS ,, this (unit_price) depends on the order_unit if the (order_unit) equals 'ton' then the (unit_price) equals (Price_ton) in the ITEMS table when (item_code) in ITEMS equals (Item_code_orders) in ORDERITEMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted earlier you can't use a WHEN clause as you'd originally tried because you can't use fields from multiple tables in the WHEN clause.  It looks like you need to fetch the row from ITEMS which has an ITEM_CODE matching the ORDER_ITEMS_CODE on your ORDER_ITEMS row, and then copy the appropriate field from the ITEM_CODE row to the ORDER_ITEMS row.

Try this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER Orderitems_T1
  BEFORE insert or update on orderitems
  for each row
declare
  rowItems  ITEMS%ROWTYPE;
begin
  SELECT *
    INTO rowItems
    FROM ITEMS i
    WHERE i.ITEM_CODE = :NEW.ORDER_ITEMS_CODE;

  case
    when :NEW.order_unit = 'sheet' then
      :NEW.unit_price := rowItems.price_sheet;
    when :NEW.order_unit = 'ton' then
      :NEW.unit_price := rowItems.price_ton ;
    when :NEW.order_unit = 'ream' then
      :NEW.unit_price := rowItems.price_ream ;
    else
      :NEW.unit_price := 0;
  end case;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No row found in ITEMS for ' ||
                         'ORDERITEMS.ORDER_ITEMS_CODE=''' ||
                         :NEW.ORDER_ITEMS_CODE || '''');
    RAISE;  -- re-raise the error if an invalid item code is found
end Orderitems_T1;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting this errors 
[PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge The symbol "case" was substituted for "WHEN" to continue.] and [ PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: case]

Comment: I'd thought the ORDER_UNIT field was on the ITEMS table.  Try it again.

Comment: The above code compiles without errors for me.  I'm not sure what I can tell you...

Comment: I keep getting the same errors, don't know why!! but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntactical errors.
Can you please try and run the below code

```
create or replace TRIGGER "Orderitems_T1"
BEFORE
insert or update on orderitems
for each row
when (item_code_orders = item_code )
--begin   --remove this begin
AS
order_unit                        orderitems.order_unit%type;
unit_price                         orderitems.unit_price%type;
price_sheet                      Items.price_sheet%type;
price_ream                       Items.price_ream%type;
price_ton                           Items.price_ton%type;
item_code                         Items.item_code%type;
item_code_orders         orderitems.item_code_orders%type;

begin
case
when order_unit ='sheet' then  unit_price :=  price_sheet;
when order_unit = 'ton'  then  unit_price := price_ton ;
when order_unit = 'ream'  then  unit_price := price_ream ;
else order_unit := 0;
end case;
end;
```

Comment: Now I'm getting ORA-04076: invalid NEW or OLD specification!